# iterate nested loop in thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, frontend, thymeleaf

Feed

```
package com.v2.search.p;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Field;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.FieldType;
@Document(indexName = "feeds")
public class feed {
    
    @Id
    private Integer feed_id;
    
    public Integer getFeed_id() {
        return feed_id;
    }

    public void setFeed_id(Integer feed_id) {
        this.feed_id = feed_id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    public List<Comment> getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(List<Comment> comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text, name = "title")
    private String title;
    
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text, name = "body")
    private String body;
    
    @Field(type= FieldType.Nested , name="comment")  
    private List<Comment> comment;

    
}
```

Subfield= comment

```
package com.v2.search.p;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Comment {
    @JsonProperty("c_id")
    private String c_id;

    @JsonProperty("feed_id")
    private String feed_id;

    @JsonProperty("c_text")
    private String c_text;

    public String getC_id() {
        return c_id;
    }

    public void setC_id(String c_id) {
        this.c_id = c_id;
    }

    public String getFeed_id() {
        return feed_id;
    }

    public void setFeed_id(String feed_id) {
        this.feed_id = feed_id;
    }

    public String getC_text() {
        return c_text;
    }

    public void setC_text(String c_text) {
        this.c_text = c_text;
    }


}
```

```
<table id="feeds" border="1" class="table table-striped table-responsive-md">
        <thead class="table-dark">
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>body</th>
            <th>title</th>
            <th>comment 1</th>
            <th>comment 1a</th>
            <th>comment 1b</th>
            
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
    
        <tr th:each="feedDocument : ${listfeedDocuments}">
            <td th:text="${feedDocument.feed_id}"></td>
            <td th:text="${feedDocument.title}"></td>
            <td th:text="${feedDocument.body}"></td>
            <td th:each ="cd : ${feedDocument.comment}"</td>
            <td  th:text="${cd.get(0).c_text}"></td>
            <td  th:text="${cd.get(1).c_text}"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

listfeedDocument contain the fields as well one array list of comment that is defined in another class with some attributes i want to iterate another loop like cd to get the values of comment array list withits attribute like c_text,c_id but it showing me following error :
**Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "cd.get(0).c_text" **

Comment: You have `th:next` instead of `th:each`... the variable `${cd}` probably doesn't exist because of that.  (You might also consider a `th:block` here instead of a `td`.

Comment: @Metroids i have changed the code but doesnt solve the problem can you please help me

Comment: The code in your question is missing a closing `</td>` at one point. You can [edit] your question to show the current version of the code and the related error message. Otherwise, we don't know what _actual_ code you are executing. Some test data would be useful, also, so we can see what the Java structures are and how they are populated. See [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this way we can iterate the array list in thymeleaf and get our desired result

```
<!--this is my text for comments iteration -->
    
    <div th:each="feedDocument : ${listfeedDocuments}"> 
       <th:block th:each="tx : ${feedDocument}"> 
       <th:block th:each="x: ${tx.comment}">
       <div th:text="${x.c_text}"></div>
       </th:block>
      </th:block>
   </th:div>
```